# How to edit tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets, jax

I imported CIFAR10 dataset via `tensorflow_dataset.load()`.

This gives me `<PrefetchDataset element_spec={'id': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None), 'image': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), 'label': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)}>`

This dataset has an id column. I want to remove this id. Becuase this id gives casuses an exception in jax. [Why JAX throws an unfiltered stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73860749/why-jax-throws-an-unfiltered-stack-trace/73861494#comment130958076_73861494)
Guess I can convert it into panda dataframe but is their a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
result = ds.map(lambda x: {
    'image': x['image'],
    'label': x['label']
})

result.element_spec
>>> <MapDataset element_spec={'image': TensorSpec(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), 'label': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tfds.as_numpy` you can get the dataset in the form of a dictionary and easily delete a column:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds_builder = tfds.builder('cifar10')
ds_builder.download_and_prepare()
data = tfds.as_numpy(ds_builder.as_dataset(split='train', batch_size=-1))

print(type(data))
# <class 'dict'>

print(data.keys())
# dict_keys(['id', 'image', 'label'])

del data['id']
print(data.keys())
# dict_keys(['image', 'label'])
```

This is also the form you'll need to get the dataset into JAX.